# got MissingPropertException from Jmeter while using addArgument for http Request sampler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, jmeter, load-testing

i am trying to do a load test for a registration scenario, and i am completely new to the jmeter.
with some help from gpt i did a scripting in JSR332 sampler to dynamically create username and email till the count of thread group, so each time a new username and email will be created and i can pass the username and email with default password, but i am getting error from it,
Consider i have 2 thread groups

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrYD5.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLL9B.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iNU3.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mu1T.png)

Comment: Could you include the images inline in your post instead of linking out?

Comment: Linked out to images that would be nice to include inline.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you use `registration` object but you don't [instantiate](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html) it anywhere.

Given you don't understand what does the code do I would suggest asking the person or LLM who provided you this code to fix this going forward.

As an exception I provide you the hint so at least just this error will go away, you will need to add the next line before first access to the `registration` object:

```
def registration = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
```

- More information on Groovy scirpting in general: [Groovy Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html)
- More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)